# Identify development or production in expressjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I know we can set `NODE_ENV = "development"` in env file and call from server files const  `process.env.NODE_ENV;`

But I want check it from client-side js files which imported in EJS

```
app.js // server starting file
view/home.ejs (<script src="/js/home.js"></script>)
js/home.js
.env (NODE_ENV = "development")
```

from home.js , I have to check development or production to avoid console.log output in production

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"){
    console.log("home page loaded message")
}
```

Comment: You can't use `process.env` client-side (it's only available in Node)

Comment: You can add a special route to get this mode from server-side on client-side